# Edit some Google Files on the desktop without installing Google Drive

Tags: microsoft-excel, plugins, libreoffice-calc, openoffice-calc, google-drive

I would like to edit a Google Tabel on my Desktop with out installing the Drive Client (I really only need this file) and with out using the browser. What can I do? Is there a plug-in for excle or calc? Note I tryed GMDesk, it doesn't work great (plus it is seems nothing more than a flash baesd browser, there I could really use the real one).

Answer (score 0):

Google actually recently released a plugin for office which you can use to edit files on your drive directly. You can download it [here](http://googledrive.blogspot.nl/2015/07/google-drive-plug-in-for-office.html)

I've used it myself and it works pretty well. You can browse drive from office and open/save any file stored in your Google drive.